# check connection function with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, connection

I want to check internet connection with a test, with jquery

my js:

```
/* detect connexion */
function detectConnexionTest() {

  var urlOnline = "/connect";

  jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: urlOnline,
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
      console.log(xhr.status);
      detectConnexion("yes");
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(xhr.status);
      detectConnexion("no");
    }
  });
}

function detectConnexion(value) {
  if (value == "yes") {
    return true;
  } else if (value == "no") {
    return false;
  } else {
    return false;

  }
}
```

and after, the calling in a angularjs controller :

```
detectConnexionTest();
if (detectConnexion() === true) {
    $scope.online = "connected";
} else if (detectConnexion() === false) {
    $scope.online = "not connected";
}
```

html :

```
<p>are you connected ? : {{online}}</p>
```

i'm confused about call the testing function detectConnexionTest , and my scope show me always "not connected" even if i'm connected and get "200" status... what's wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You call `detectConnexionTest()` which ***begins*** an AJAX request and returns immediately
2. You call `detectConnexion()` with no parameter immediatly afterwards, which is guaranteed to return false even if your AJAX request had completed
3. When your AJAX call does return, you call `detectConnexion()` and do pass a value and it will return true or false, but you don't store that return value.
4. Since you're using `jQuery.ajax()`, angular does not know when your call returns so even if you did update a value on your scope properly your page would not update until angular went through another digest cycle.

What you should probably do is use `$http` and set the scope value when the call returns:

```
function TestCtrl($scope, $http) {
  function detectConnexion() {
    $http.post("/connect").success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.online = "connected";
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.online = "not connected";
    }
  }

  detectConnexion();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting it wrong, try to understand how AJAX works, this is one way to do it pretty similar to what you've got there:

Change the detectConnexion function to this:

```
function detectConnexion(value) {
  if (value == "yes") {
    connected = true;
  } else if (value == "no") {
    connected = false;
  } else {
    connected = false;
  }
}
```

And change the code in the angular controller to this:

```
detectConnexionTest();
if (connected === true) {
    $scope.online = "connected";
} else if (connected === false) {
    $scope.online = "not connected";
}
```

Comment: PS: I'm not so familiar with angular and i can't tell you for sure if the connected global variable will be visible in the angular controller

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code, it's cleaned a bit.

```js
function detectConnexionTest() {
  var urlOnline = "/connect";

  jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: urlOnline,
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
      detectConnexion(true);
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      detectConnexion(false);
    }
  });
}

function detectConnexion(b) {
    $scope.online = b ? "connected" : "not connected";
}

detectConnexionTest();
```

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest way to do this is with the navigator.onLine property. You could implement the javascript to run when a button is pressed. You can put it into a simple if, else statement. Read more here:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_online.asp

Example:

```
function checkConnection() {
    if (navigator.onLine) {
       // Action
    } else {
       // Action
    }
}
```